# 'span' of R arrays

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array `a` of dimension `I x J` and array `b` of dimension `K`. I want to create an array `c` of dimension `I x J x K` such that `c[i,j,k] = f( a[i,j], b[k] )`, for `f` some function.

I know that this can obviously be done with a for-loop, but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome. Is there any more convenient (vectorized) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with `outer(a, b, f)`, e.g.

```r
a <- array(1:6, dim=c(2,3))
b <- array(1:4, dim = 4)
outer(a, b, function(a, b) a + b/10)
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  1.1  3.1  5.1
#> [2,]  2.1  4.1  6.1
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  1.2  3.2  5.2
#> [2,]  2.2  4.2  6.2
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  1.3  3.3  5.3
#> [2,]  2.3  4.3  6.3
#> 
#> , , 4
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  1.4  3.4  5.4
#> [2,]  2.4  4.4  6.4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that `outer()` assumes `f` is vectorized; if not, pass in `Vectorize(f)`.